# SQL Select two values

Tags: sql

I am trying to optimize my code where I have to run two queries, 1 to count how many houses there are with the same address at the input and 2 count how many values there are in the table total.

Here are my queries.

Count address's from input:

```
SELECT Count(addr) FROM housedata WHERE addr = %s
```

Count total amount of rows:

```
SELECT Count(ID) FROM housedata
```

Is there any way of merging these into the same query?
Thanks peeps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    Count(addr) AS ADDR_COUNT,
    (SELECT Count(ID) FROM housedata) AS TOTAL_COUNT
FROM housedata
WHERE addr = %s
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
SELECT sum(case when addr =%s then 1 else 0 end) , count(Id) FROM housedata
```

Comment: Close but `count(0)` still counts as one. Either change `count()` to `sum()` or `ELSE 0` to `ELSE NULL` or completely omit it, as `NULL` is the default if no condition matches.

Comment: This seems to throw back an error when I run it, even after I have tried what @stickybit suggested

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT Count(addr) AS CNT_ADR FROM housedata WHERE addr = '%s'),
B AS (
SELECT Count(ID) AS CNT_ID FROM housedata)
SELECT A.CNT_ADR, B.CNT_ID
FROM A, B;
```

Comment: I get this error "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."